# JSCS process timeout in Webstorm

Tags: webstorm, jscs

I often get the following error in Webstorm when working with a .jscs file.

`JSCS: JSCS process timeout`

What does that mean?
Normally, if my Javascript code fails the style checks, I get error marks and it is shown what is not correct. But this behaviour looks like a deeper problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special. JSCS is run as external process from WebStorm. If WebStorm doesn't receive response from this process for more than 10 sec (may happen if the read access to file is blocked, for example), this error occurs. process will be restarted on next file change